# Find which graphic card in use

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, terminal

My laptop has two graphic cards, Nvidia and Intel. I'm using Archlinux.

I want to know which graphic card the X server is using.
What is the command line command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the glxinfo package installed? For me, this produces the expected output.
`glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"`

Credit to: [Nickolai](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185062)